# ¿Como realizar un programa que solicite dos valores enteros y decir cuales mayor,menor o bien si son iguales?

Tags: c++, parametros

```
int valor;
int ValorA,ValorB;

cout << "Ingresar 2 valores enteros: ";
cin >> valor;

return valor;  

 int main(){
 int ValorA,ValorB;
 ValorA = solicitarValor();
 ValorB = solicitarValor();

   if(ValorA==ValorB){
    cout << ValorA << " y " <<ValorB << " Son numeros iguales." <<endl; 
    }else if
     (ValorA>ValorB){
        cout <<ValorA << " Es el mayor " "y " <<ValorB << " Es el menor"<< endl;
    }else{
    cout <<ValorB << " Es el mayor " "y " <<ValorA << " Es el menor"<< endl;
```

Como realizar un programa que solicite 2 valores enteros, y mediante un procedimiento muestre en pantalla cual es el mayor, cual es el menor, o bien si son iguales.El problema que tengo es de los IF que puse en el main, era lo que debía ir dentro del procedimiento, y no tengo el procedimiento.**No tengo claro donde poner el procedimiento, y con el verbo infinitivo.**

```
El procedimiento recibe 2 variable tipo int como parámetros de entrada.
 Este internamente tiene unos condicionales para determinar cual es mayor y cual es menor, o si ambas son iguales.
Este muestra en pantalla los resultados correspondientes.

Ejemplo:
Computadora: ingrese un valor numérico entero
Usuario: 5
Computadora: ingrese un valor numérico entero
Usuario: 8
Computadora: 5 es el menor y 8 es el mayor.
```

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: Es que la lógica de los IF era lo que debía ir dentro del procedimiento, y no tengo el procedimiento.

Comment: Cuál procedimiento? La función `solicitarValor()`?

Comment: Los IF son los que tengo que poner dentro del procedimiento.

Comment: Pero el pregunta, dentro de que procedimiento deben ir los if, por que no queda claro a que te refieres al decir que deben ir dentro.. dentro de que, con que nombre?

Comment: if(ValorA==ValorB){
  cout << ValorA << " y " <<ValorB << " Son numeros iguales." <<endl; 
 }else if
      (ValorA>ValorB){
       cout <<ValorA << " Es el mayor " "y " <<ValorB << " Es el menor"<< endl;
     }else{
     cout <<ValorB << " Es el mayor " "y " <<ValorA << " Es el menor"<< endl;

Comment: Necesito crear el procedimiento y eso va dentro de ese procedimiento con un verbo infinitivo.

Comment: Es claro que no tienes el procedimiento en tu código. ¿Qué problema tienes al crear el procedimiento? Qué duda tienes?

Comment: No tengo claro de donde poner el procedimiento, ¿estará bien donde lo puse los IF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas crear un método aparte que compare los dos números:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void comparar(int ValorA, int ValorB){
    if(ValorA==ValorB){
        cout << ValorA << " y " << ValorB << " son números iguales." << endl;
    }
    else if(ValorA>ValorB){
        cout << ValorA << " es el mayor " "y " << ValorB << " es el menor" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << ValorB << " es el mayor " "y " << ValorA << " es el menor" << endl;
    }   
}

int main() {
    int ValorA, ValorB;
    cout << "Ingresar 2 valores enteros: ";
    cin >> ValorA >> ValorB;
    comparar(ValorA, ValorB);
}
```

En este caso, el usuario debe ingresar los dos números separados por un espacio, por ejemplo: `5 8` y el programa le mostrará `8 es el mayor y 5 es el menor`.
A menos que sea obligatorio crear un método aparte para realizar la comparación, poner todo ese bloque de sentencias dentro del método `main`, no estaría mal.

Comment: Excelente gracias.