# ¿Como crear un programa que solicite al usuario un valor entero positivo y retorne si es par o impar?

Tags: c++, string

```
int solicitarNum(){
    string Num;
    cout << "Ingresar un numero: ";
    cin >> Num;
}

int main(){
    int numero;
    string Num;

    Num = solicitarNum();


    if (numero % 2==0){
        cout << "El numero ingresado es par. ";
    }
    else{
        cout << "El numero ingresado es impar. ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Voy realizar un programa que solicite al usuario un valor entero positivo y mediante una función retorne si es par o impar, el programa mostrara el tipo de valor ingresado.

La función tendra como parámetro de entrada un valor int y tendrá como valor de retorno un  string.
Dentro de esta habrá un condicional que determina:
Si el valor es par, la función retorna Par.
Si no, la función retorna Impar.

```
Ejemplo.
Computadora: Ingrese un valor entero positivo:
Usuario: 79
Computadora: El valor ingresado es Impar.
```

Mi problema es:
La lógica de los IF que puse en el main,
era lo que debía de ir dentro de la función,
y no tengo la función , **y esa es mi duda  como ubicar bien eso en la función**

Comment: Y cuál es el problema que da ese código?

Comment: *La lógica de los IF que puse en el main, era lo que debía de ir dentro del procedimiento, y no tengo el procedimiento, y no tengo claro eso y es mi duda*... Ahora nosotros también tenemos la duda porque no se entiende cuál es tu problema.

Comment: Que no tengo hecha la función es el problema en el ejercicio.

Comment: Yo veo que tienes una función ya definida. Y si te hace fata una ¿Qué hace, cómo es, cuáles entradas tiene, que salida tiene? ¿Qué es lo que no puedes hacer?

Comment: Que la lógica de los IF de la main, es la que tengo que poner dentro de la función.

Comment: Ponla dentro del la función.

Comment: Esa es mi duda como ubicar  bien eso en la función.

Comment: *Cómo ubicar bien eso en la función* pues ... cortando y pegando, porque por lo demás funciona correctamente. No tiene dificultad alguna, literalmente, corta el código del main, pégalo en la función y renombra las variables para que se llamen igual... ya está!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como realizar un programa que solicite dos valores enteros y decir cuales mayor,menor o bien si son iguales?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/404524/como-realizar-un-programa-que-solicite-dos-valores-enteros-y-decir-cuales-mayor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo estás poco confundido , mira a grandes rasgos así deberías de interactuar con funciones , lo que quieres según entiendo es tu lógica del if (que es de validar si es par o no ) ponerla en otra función

```
Main(){
    solicitarNum() 
    validaPar()
}

solicitarNum() { 
   // lógica
}

validaPar(){
   // lógica del tu if
}
```

Comment: Excelente gracias por la guía, si es que estaba confundido con eso.